# I'm trying to make a tweet with grackle, but I get an error:

Tags: ruby, json, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'grackle'
require 'json'
require 'highline/import'



$client = Grackle::Client.new(:auth => {
    :type => :auth,
    :consumer_key => 'TxnvsqOEHdCTlO2CYBIjw',
    :consumer_secret =>  'consumer secret',
    :token => '2203948560-sfGAMQT69FmSWYrfwuBL2Y3ISyfhB3X3OJ1dyQ2',
    :token_secret => 'token secret'
    })

class Twitter


    @@input = ""

    def getJsonData
        @json = $client.users.show? :screen_name => 'LenguajesP' #http://twitter.com/users/show.json?screen_name=LenguajesP
    end

    def parseIt
        puts @json.name
        puts @json.location
        puts @json.description
    end

    def getTweet
        @@input = ask("Introduzca tweet")
        puts @@input
    end

    def tweet

        $client.statuses.update! :status=> @@input #POST to https://twitter.com/statuses/update.json
    end
end
```

This is the error:

```
Grackle::TwitterError: get http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=LenguajesP => 400: {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/grackle-0.3.0/lib/grackle/client.rb:296:in `handle_error_response'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/grackle-0.3.0/lib/grackle/client.rb:274:in `process_response'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/grackle-0.3.0/lib/grackle/client.rb:248:in `call_with_format'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/grackle-0.3.0/lib/grackle/client.rb:228:in `append'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/grackle-0.3.0/lib/grackle/client.rb:166:in `method_missing'
    from twit.rb:23:in `tweet'
    from (irb):43
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You really shouldn't post your auth data, but with that said, you need to pass some form of authentication to make that API call.

Comment: Also, the last update to Grackle was 8 months ago, so it may not work with the current Twitter API.